# C# Easy drag and drop way to create DataTables from SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, console-application

When dealing with really small apps and the sqlbulkcopy, I normally create datatables by either using a FILL on an empty datatable OR I just type out something like this

```
DataTable dtGrps = new DataTable();
dtGrps.Columns.Add("objectGuid", typeof(Guid));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("DN", typeof(string));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("CN", typeof(string));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("groupType", typeof(string));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("description", typeof(string));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("whenCreated", typeof(string));
dtGrps.Columns.Add("whenChanged", typeof(string));
```

but it occurred to me that surly there is a built in way (non EF or Linq) to create all the code above by some drag in drop method. I mean I am using VS2017, surely MS has added this feature and I have just missed it is all.

So does this exist?

Comment: Why use DataTables in the first place? Why not strongly typed objects, and then use an ORM?

Comment: There is such functionality for Windows Forms apps -- the [strongly typed `DataSet` generator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/04y282hb). The code that produces is not necessarily the kind you'd want to copy into your own project, though.

Comment: @mason - because I'm using sqlbulkcopy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rough implementation, just intended as a starting point because my goal here isn't to write a new library. It could use a lot of optimization. But you can use strongly typed objects, use reflection to generate a DataTable based on the objects, and then use SqlBulkCopy to insert that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;

namespace StronglyStypedSqlBulkCopy
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Car> cars = GetSampleData();
            DataTable dataTable = ConvertToDataTable(cars);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static List<Car> GetSampleData()
        {
            return new List<Car> {
                new Car { Id = 1, Make = "Toyota", Model = "Tacoma", DateOfManufacture = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
                new Car { Id = 2, Make = "Ford", Model = "Raptor", DateOfManufacture = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) },
                new Car { Id = 3, Make = "Ram", Model = "1500", DateOfManufacture = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3) }
            };
        }

        public static DataTable ConvertToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> objects)
        {
            var properties = objects.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();

            var table = new DataTable();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var columnName = property.Name; //may want to get from attribute also
                //probably want to define an explicit mapping of .NET types to SQL types, and allow an attribute to specifically specify the SQL type
                table.Columns.Add(columnName, property.PropertyType);
            }

            //probably want to cache the mapping from above in a real implementation

            foreach (var obj in objects)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();

                foreach (var property in properties)
                {
                    var columnName = property.Name; //may want to get from attribute also
                    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(obj);
                    row[columnName] = propertyValue;
                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            return table;
        }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Make { get; set; }

        public string Model { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateOfManufacture { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Once you have a nice implementation of ConvertToDataTable, it's simply a matter of defining strongly typed classes, which are much easier to work with than raw DataTables.